# Failed to handle null or empty recordset in VB6

Tags: vb6, null

It's been a day I've cracked my head to solve this....I've googled for solutions but none of it resolve my issue...

The code is like this:

```
    Private Sub guh()
Dim oConn As Connection
Dim Record As Recordset
Dim SqlStr As String

SqlStr = "select * from dbo.Msg_History where Client_ID='2' AND Update_Msg='4'"
Set oConn = New Connection

With oConn
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.CommandTimeout = 0
.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=Table_Msg;UID=Admin;PWD="

End With

Set Record = oConn.Execute(SqlStr)

If IsNull(Record) Then
    MsgBox "There are no records"

    Else
    MsgBox "There are records"

End If

oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The sql statement is returning null recordset ..when i run the code...it always go to the "else" condition which is the line MsgBox "There are records"

I've tried change the line : If IsNull(Record) Then

to

If IsNull(Record.Fields(0).Value) Then

but then it throws an error like this:-

error: Either BOF or EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

I've checked http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304267 and use eof and bof to the condition...n still get the same error..

please anyone help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
' returns true if there is non empty recordset
Function isRSExists(rs) AS boolean
  ' has to exists as object
  If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    ' has to be opened with recordset (could be empty)
    If rs.State > 0 Then
      ' has to have some records
      If Not rs.EOF Then
         isRSExists = true
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think this is overkill in context. They probably would want an exception when `rs Is Nothing` because getting no recordset returned from a vanilla `SELECT` would suggest a serious environment problem (e.g. table has been dropped).

Comment: I assume that in case of dropped table `Execute` raise exception... It's overkill for example from question (plain SQL), but in case of result from calling stored procedure or VB function returning recordset it's not.

Comment: why am i having to google how to do vb6 when the year is 2016??!!

Comment: @davesol because we have to maintain and fix old software!! (It is 2017 now!!)

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
If IsNull(Record) Then
```

to

```
If Record.RecordCount = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can test for `if not Record.Eof`.

If I recall correctly (it's been a long time), it only works with one type of cursor, I think it should be `adUseServer`. (**EDIT** *No, it's actually RecordCount which has this problem*)

I'll try and dig out some old code to check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys :D ...will test it later anyway...I havent's tested all of your suggestions at the time I'm posting this reply...I tested this: –

If Record.BOF And Record.EOF Then

and this works...

Comment: thanks for the feedback. You can add comments on to answers, or to your question, rather than creating a new 'answer'. Note that you can also show your appreciation by voting. And if one question provides 'the' answer, you can mark it as accepted (with the checkmark). In my opinion, @Grzegorz deserves the check mark.

Comment: Just test EOF _OR_ .RecordCount = 0. No need to test BOF as well. Testing both EOF and BOF is something that needed to be done in older technologies e.g. DAO (and RDO?) Happily, they fixed this with when they designed ADO.

Comment: Benjol : sorry for that...now checking again my questions...i was in a rush that day actually..noted that...thanks :) ...but I wonder y is this line "If IsNull(Record) Then" not working..I've tested this line with another variable type variant and set it to null...it works wonderful..but y does it fail with recordset??